# beginner: how to predict multiple boolean outputs (keras / tensor flow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Sorry for this beginners question:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

dataset = loadtxt('set/20180310.csv', delimiter=',')

X = dataset[:,10:]
y = dataset[:,2:10]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(72, input_dim=48, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, [y], epochs=50, batch_size=10)

# make class predictions with the model
predictions = model.predict_classes(X)
predict = model.predict(X)
```

`predictions` simply gives me a stupid array (of samples length) with integers

`predict` at least for each sample gives me an output array of length 8,
but i can not make sense of predict array.

Yes i am know knowing what i am doing :-(
But it will only take you a few seconds to correct my code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you have 8 classes (for what I can see in the sigmoid layer)

`predict = model.predict(X)` will return `n` where `n` is a list of lists. `n` has samples lenght and each list in `n` has lenght 8 because is the number of possible classes. So `n` will contain the probabilities list for each one of the input samples. For example. for one of the input samples in X, called `X[i]`, the output would be: `[0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]`. And a similar list will be generated for each one of the input samples, giving you the list of lists `n`, returned by `model.predict(X)`.

`predictions = model.predict_classes(X)` returns a samples lenght list containing integers between [0-7] (because of 8 classes). Each one of those integers represents the class to which each one of the input in `X` belongs. In the example above, `X[i]` belongs with probability 0.9 to the class 2 (because the 0.9 is at index 2), so `model.predict_classes(X)` will return 2 for `X[i]` and other integers for the rest of input samples in `X`.

Comment: Big thanks, so `predict_classes(X)` gives a "pointer" to the most probable class like `5 (expected [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])` = 5 points to the 1.0 of the correct outputs ?  As i want all the outputs i use `model.predict(X)` and with 500 epochs i indeed get   [0.98 0.   0.   0.   0.99 0.   0.   0.  ] (expected [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])` and so on. Only with 50 epochs the fit was so bad that i took the predict for wrong. Thank you very much for helping me out :-)

Comment: In your example the "pointer" would be 4, not 5 (the index start at 0). If you get the solution, mark the answer as solved :-)

Comment: agreed but the code did output 5 so i assumed the index starts at 1. Anyway `predict(X)` is what i need and now works like a charm. Thank you for giving me a happy end to 2019 :-)